# PHP: summarize objects of user

Tags: php, class, object, cmsmadesimple

I have a module in CMSmadesimple which makes 'registrations'. A registration is a class in php with id user and registerstatus.

How can I summarize all users (not just the ones who have a registration) and afther them if they are registrated or not.

the class (nb_persons is used as registration status)

```
class EventsManager_registration
{
    protected $table = 'events_registrations';

    protected $custom_fields = array(
        'id_event'=>'',
        'id_user'=>'',
        'nb_persons'=>0,
        'dr_reden'=>''
    );
```

I know how to summarize the events
    foreach from=$registrations item='registration'
but I want to summarize my users with their registration or not

Comment: I an not sure I understand what you mean by "summarize".

Comment: user 1 -> registration
user 2 -> registration
user 3 -> registration
etc...
now I can only do (cause it is a class)
registration 1 -> user
registration 2 -> user
etc